# Internet doesn't work un Ubuntu on Vmware but works onLubuntu

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, network-manager, vmware

Suddenly, Network stopped working on Ubuntu, I'm using it on VMware workstation.
I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 but the same result.
However, the internet works on Lubuntu.

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:77:61:e9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

Comment: Being specific with release details (Ubuntu and Lubuntu) are useful. You've not said what release your paste relates to (having tagged two raises more questions than it answers), thus the difference is like not Ubuntu/Lubuntu, but software stack difference but without release details we don't have any of that knowledge. Please clarify.  *Also are you talking Ubuntu Desktop? which excluding installer, packages, is identical to Lubuntu in my experience, or Ubuntu Server which is different, or a Ubuntu Core release which is even more different. Details matter.*

Answer (score 0):

It has to be related to the virtual network interface.
Check that the Network Interface in the VMWare configuration for the Ubuntu guest is Enabled, and that is assigned to the right interface (you can assign to several interfaces, to the wifi interface...).
Also check what are you using on the VM that works vs the Ubuntu which doesn't work: are you using NAT, bridged networking?.
Please check: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html
Cheers

Comment: I tried with NAT, Bridged and no changes

Comment: What do you have on the VM that works?.

Comment: windows and Lubuntu

Comment: I refer to what Network Configuration do you have in the VM that works (NAT, Bridged).
The problem is likely yo be in the virtual interface on the VM for that Ubuntu. Either it is disabled from Virtual Box, either is assigned to a wrong physical interface (another NIC or Wifi device) either is using a wrong network configuration (Host only, NAT...) that's why I ask to compare to the ones that work.

Comment: I tried with 3 versions of Ubuntu. None is working. I can't even find the internet configuration on the top right side.

Comment: The problem is not in Ubuntu. Is in VMWare Workstation. Check things like is Enabled "Connect at Power on". Here it explains detailed what I mean https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html